# Divided differences of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I am interested in computing divided differences of polynomials in a numerically stable way. Therefore I want to prove/disprove the following formula:
$$\left(x^{n+m}\right)[x_1,\dots,x_n] = \sum_{1\leq i_0\leq\dots\leq i_m\leq n} x_{i_0}\dots x_{i_m} \qquad \forall x_1,\dots, x_n\in\mathbb{R} \text{ and } \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ and } \forall m\in\mathbb{N}_0.$$
I have tried to prove it by induction on $n$. I have shown it is true for a few small values of $m$. Does someone have a clue whether the equation holds in general?

Comment: If the notaition is confusing, what I mean is $f[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $f(x)=x^{n+m}$.

Comment: Your explanatory comment doesn't help. What kind of thing is $x$?

Comment: $x$ is the argument of the function $f(x) = x^{n+m}$. The notation is a bit stupid. I can write it as $\left(x\mapsto x^{n+m}\right)[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ if that is more understandable.

Comment: Anyway, I and my brother managed to prove the equation is true. I will post a proof later if noone does it before me.

Comment: So how are you applying a function of one argument $x$ to a list of arguments $[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$? Please do post your proof as that may help us understand what your questions actually means.

Comment: See Definition -> Notation on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences

Comment: Thank you for your clarification of the notation. I look forward to seeing your proof.